# Classic - I´m a newbe in Bitcoin and Bitcoin core offered me a fee and I accepted it. It was very low (see details)

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-fees

The transaction has not been confirmed for over 14 days. Is it normal? Am I going to see my BTC ever again? :( Thank you all very much for any help!
Details:
Stav: 0/nepotvrzeno, v transakčním zásobníku
Datum: 21.12.2017 16:38
Pro: 18hSgrZD5CpPftpjPZMhWy9K7hFmmCZUop
Výdaj: -0.03419607 BTC
Transakční poplatek: -0.00000340 BTC
Čistá částka: -0.03419947 BTC
ID transakce: 3857e01084275a0259efee900b30ecd985a81b7e8a30ed53a5853ff9a73d670e
Celková velikost transakce: 339 bytes
Pořadí výstupu: 0

Comment: Really, Bitcoin core offered you a fee? How did you get that?

Comment: Please don´t solve your miserable life on me. I will not reply on this scrap. Please don´t write me Nicolas Barbulesco thx.

Comment: Thx Matthew, yes, I´m studying the thread. I just wondered if 14 days are normal and I can either expect return of BTC to my wallet or whether it will pass through one day. Should I try double spend?